# how to find the first three max length of array in JSON

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json

i had a JSON like below

```
sampleArray=[{name:'john',hobbies:['sports','music']},
                 {name:'steve',hobbies:['singing','movies','playing']},
                 {name:'raj',hobbies:['movies']},
                 {name:'nikil',hobbies:['music','movies','playing','tennis']},
                 {name:'bose',hobbies:['sports','music']},
                 {name:'suku',hobbies:['music']},
                 {name:'sai',hobbies:['sports','music','watchingTv','movies','tennis']},
                 {name:'vivek',hobbies:['sports']},
                 {name:'ram',hobbies:['sports','music','watching']}]
```

now based on hobbies array length, first three maximum array lengths objects have to push to one array and remaining objects have to push to another array

what i am expecting is like

```
 resultantArray1=[{name:'sai',hobbies:['sports','music','watchingTv','movies','tennis']},
                  {name:'nikil',hobbies:['music','movies','playing','tennis']},
                  {name:'steve',hobbies:['singing','movies','playing']}]



 resultantArray2=[{name:'john',hobbies:['sports','music']},
                  {name:'raj',hobbies:['movies']},
                  {name:'bose',hobbies:['sports','music']},
                  {name:'suku',hobbies:['music']},
                  {name:'vivek',hobbies:['sports']},
                  {name:'ram',hobbies:['sports','music','watching']}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sort by length of the hobbies and then just put the top 3 into the `resultantArray1` and the rest to the `resultantArray2`

```js
var sampleArray=[
                 {name:'john',hobbies:['sports','music']},
                 {name:'steve',hobbies:['singing','movies','playing']},
                 {name:'raj',hobbies:['movies']},
                 {name:'nikil',hobbies:['music','movies','playing','tennis']},
                 {name:'bose',hobbies:['sports','music']},
                 {name:'suku',hobbies:['music']},
                 {name:'sai',hobbies:['sports','music','watchingTv','movies','tennis']},
                 {name:'vivek',hobbies:['sports']},
                 {name:'ram',hobbies:['sports','music','watching']}
                ];

sampleArray.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.hobbies.length - a.hobbies.length;
});

var resultantArray1 = [].concat(sampleArray);
var resultantArray2 = resultantArray1.splice(3);

console.log(sampleArray);
console.log(resultantArray1);
console.log(resultantArray2);
```